# overrided operator doesn't work

Tags: c#, overriding

I have created custom linkedlist class. In this class i have

```
public bool Contains( Object obj )
        {
            for( Node curr = Start; curr != null; curr = curr.Next)
            {
                if( curr.Data == obj )
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

In Workman.cs i have overriden == operator:

```
class Workman
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string PartCode { get; set; }
        public int PartCount { get; set; }

        public int DaysWorked { get; set; }
        public int PartsMade { get; set; }
        public double PriceSum { get; set; }

        public Workman(DateTime date, string lastName, string partCode, int partCount)
        {
            Date = date;
            LastName = lastName;
            PartCode = partCode;
            PartCount = partCount;
        }

        public Workman() { }

        public override string ToString ()
        {
            return string.Format ("[Workman: LastName={0}, PartCode={1}, PartCount={2}", LastName, PartCode, PartCount);
        }

        public override bool Equals (object obj)
        {
            return this.Equals (obj as Workman);
        }

        public bool Equals(Workman workman)
        {
            if(Object.ReferenceEquals(workman, null))
                return false;
            if(this.GetType() != workman.GetType())
                return false;
            return (LastName == workman.LastName);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return LastName.GetHashCode();
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Workman lhs, Workman rhs)
        {
            if(Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null))
            {
                if(Object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            return lhs.Equals(rhs);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Workman lhs, Workman rhs)
        {
            return !(lhs == rhs);
        }
    }
```

Now in main i have:

```
LinkedList test = new LinkedList();
test.Add2( new Workman(new DateTime(), "John", "whatever", 45));
test.Add2( new Workman(new DateTime(), "Mike", "bb", 45));

Workman work = new Workman( new DateTime(), "Mike", "bb", 45 );

if( test.Contains( work ))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Contains");
}
```

This not works. When i try to debug, line in Linkedlist.cs class `if( curr.Data == obj)` doesn't enter overriden code in Workman.cs. How can i make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *override* operators, you can only *overload* them.  You're calling the `==` operator overload with `object` parameters, not your new overload with `Workman` parameters.

I'd suggest you use `object.Equals` instead, as you've overridden that

```
if(Equals(cur.Data, obj)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: In place of `if( curr.Data == obj ...` in your `Contains` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work for you if you add a cast, because right now You're calling == on object.
i believe this will work :

```
public bool Contains( Object obj )
        {
            for( Node curr = Start; curr != null; curr = curr.Next)
            {
               if(curr.data is workman && obj is workman)
                {
                    if((workman)curr.data == (workman)obj )
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     return false;
                    }
                }
               if( curr.Data == obj )
               {
                   return true;
               }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

i'm not 100% sure so let me know if it helped you.
thanks.

Comment: I considered that option, but then this list won't work with other type of objects. I need this to be flexible.

Comment: in this case it will work with other objects than `workman` because if the `cur.data` and the parameter are not of type `workman` , it will not enter the first if ( `if( curr.data is workman && obj is workman)` ). therefore it will simply check if their equal by the second if , which refers to type `object` - ( `if( curr.Data == obj ) { return true; }` ).